# need help for widget probleme with yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

in yesod I have etat.hamlet and i need to create a widget with variable session to put it with others fils .hamlet

My code is like that, but i recive a error

```
etatwidget = do
    sess <- getSession
    let mence = unpack $ case Map.lookup "ence" sess of
        Just a -> a
        Nothing -> "Nothing"        
    $(widgetFile "etat")
```

Error :

```
Handler\Home.hs:585:5: parse error on input `$('
Build failure, pausing...
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(widgetFile "etat")` is a Template Haskell splice, so the first thing to check is whether the TemplateHaskell extension is enabled. You can enable it by adding

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
```

to the top of your source file.

P.S.: By the way, you will need to indent the `Just` and `Nothing` cases one level further as well:

```
    let mence = unpack $ case Map.lookup "ence" sess of
            Just a -> a
            Nothing -> "Nothing"
```

Comment: I added {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-} but i recive the seem error! what about just and Nothing? can you give a expmple please?

Comment: @user3002631 - updated the answer on the indentation issue. Though your problem seems unrelated, it is a syntax error as well, so fixing it might help isolating the problem.

Comment: Also....  Note that the {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-} line has to appear right at the top of the file (ie- no lines or spaces may appear above it).  I've also notices that you have created a similar file in a previous question, and that one worked, so it may help you to use that file as a template to get this to work.